# How to display changed state of checkbox before other code executes in OnCheckedChangeListener.onCheckedChanged

Tags: android

I need to add new view after clicking on checkbox. And what i want is to show changed state of checkbox and only then display new view, but now when i click on checkbox, ui stops for a second or few, and then at the same time showing new view and checkbox displaying as checked.

My code is very simple

```
{

checkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.select_param_value_checkbox);

if (checkbox != null) {

    checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            onCheckboxChanged(isChecked);

        }

    });

}
}

protected void onCheckboxChanged(boolean isChecked) {
    //this listener is adding in constructor and creates in view where i want to add child
    on_change_listener.onFilterParamValueChanged(this);
}
```

And code with that listener is:

```
public void onFilterParamValueChanged(MyClass obj) {

    addView(new MyView(getContext(), obj.getTitle()));
}
```

code of MyView:

```
class MyView extends LinearLayout{

    private TextView title;

    public MyView(Context context, String text) {
        super(context);
        ViewGroup.inflate(context, R.layout.my_view, this);
        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selected_filter_param_value_title);
        if (title != null) {
            title.setText(filter_value_data.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

**UPD**
Solution that's work for me is in comment below, thanks to @Diljeet. I put addView in Runnable

```
public void onFilterParamValueChanged(MyClass obj) {
    new Handler().post(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            addView(new MyView(getContext(), obj.getTitle()));
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: wht code u hve implemented on checkbox click or checkchanged event ? need to see code...without it cnt help ....

Comment: Show your code please. As a quick workaround I can suggest to use some animation to add a view and to use AnimationListener.

Comment: please paste your code here, you can try handler.post(new Runnable(){
....add views here
});
this should work as you want